# first Edit a running *.py file and re-run it with commands

Tags: python

I need to edit currently running py file and than re run it with new contant!
Ok
Mainest problem is that.
I want to do that:

1. Runinng in bash:

   fre‌qtrade hyper‌opt --stra‌tegy GodS‌traNew ...‌
2. It will run GodStraNew.py file as therdparty app
3. I'm now inside GodStraNew.py
4. I will stop the code after seeing this varia‌ble:

   dnaSi‌ze=‌10
5. Now will edit the GodStraNew.py file As which I want,
   for example, adding 9 lines to it.
6. than run again the hyperopt command with args, and without exiting!

Comment: Do you mean command-line arguments? Check out [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Comment: thanks yes I think it will work to me. I will make another tmp file and run a command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i find out how can I do that without need to terminal commands.
I need a temp file that will import it in spacific place and will edit this file when I run the main strategy file

```
$ cat main.py
with open("tmp.py", "w") as file1:
    # Writing data to a file
    file1.write("print('hi')\n")
    #file1.writelines(L)
import pr

$ cat tmp.py
print('hi')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no way to edit a running file
But you can make a JSON file or TXT file and store data from.
Example:

```
fileObject = open("sample.txt", "r")
data = fileObject.read()
range = data
```

And do not forget to convert the data type to Integer or float if it was a Number

Comment: Editing a running file is possible just fine. The changes are just not reflected immediately.

Comment: Yes, But he will need to put the entire python file in a loop which makes it re-run the python file every certain time.

Comment: thanks. I can do that: editing,stoping the process and parallal run the py file.I just need to stop running py file and run a bash command or windows command.

Comment: use this
`import os
import sys
os.system('ls -l)
sys.exit()`

Comment: @Crybaby your code is bad in 3 respects. First, you should be using the `with` context manager to open files: `with open("sample.txt", "r") as file_object: ...`. Second, don't name variables after builtins like `range`, as you shadow them and won't be able to use them properly later. Third, what's the point of the `data` variable if you're just going to assign it to `range`? Your 3rd line is unnecessary.

Comment: thanks alot ,but problem is bigger than that. I edited the question to explain more what I want